# Yahya and his assigned name

Tags: tafseer

Allah (swt) says that he didn't assign the name "yahya" to anyone before in quran 19:7 but in the bible, there are a few Johanan and john. Can someone please explain.
jazakallah

Comment: interprets differed about this verse . but if it was the case , the other "yahya" named people, could have been named after him , right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the Gospel's *John* is taken from the hebrew name *[Yohanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yohanan)* and not *Yahya*, which is mentioned in the Quran.

The two are not cognates.

[Yohanan](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/3076.htm) is a compound of [Yahweh](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/3068.htm) (Hebrew name of God) and [Chanan](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/2603.htm) (shows compassion) as in [Arabic حنان](https://archive.org/stream/ArabicEnglishLexicon.CopiousEasternSources.EnlargedSuppl.Kamoos.Lane.Poole.1863/02.ArabicEnglLex.v1p2.let.5.6.7..Jim.Cha.Kha.Lane1865.#page/n287/mode/2up) meaning *God has been gracious*. The Quran does not ascribe this name to the son of Zechariah (it might relate the attribute to him in [19:13](https://quran.com/19/13)), and does not claim it to be unique.

Yahya is likely a compound of the Hebrew *Yahweh* and *[Chaya](http://biblehub.com/str/hebrew/2421.htm)* or *[Haya](http://biblehub.com/str/hebrew/1961.htm)* (Ya-haya), its meaning akin to *God gave life* or *God caused to exist*. The following is from [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura3-aya39.html):

> #### قوله تعالى : بيحيى كان اسمه في الكتاب الأول حيا ، وكان اسم سارة زوجة إبراهيم عليه السلام يسارة ، وتفسيره بالعربية لا تلد ، فلما بشرت بإسحاق قيل لها : سارة ، سماها بذلك جبريل عليه السلام . فقالت : يا إبراهيم لم نقص من اسمي حرف ؟ فقال إبراهيم ذلك لجبريل عليهما السلام . فقال : ( إن ذلك الحرف زيد في اسم ابن لها من أفضل الأنبياء اسمه حي وسمي بيحيى ) . ذكره النقاش .  . وقال بعضهم : سمي بذلك لأن الله تعالى أحيا به الناس بالهدى .
>
> Allah says: *Yahya*. In the book his name was first Haya and Abraham's wife's same was Yasara ... When she was given the tidings of Isaac it was said to her Sara and this name was given to her by Gabriel. She asked Abraham why a letter was removed from her name and Abraham asked the same from Gabriel and he said that the letter has been added to the name of  her son who is of high stature among the Prophets and his name is Haye and his name has been given Yahya. Naqash has narrated this.
>
> #### وقال قتادة : سمي بيحيى لأن الله تعالى أحياه بالإيمان والنبوة
>
> Qatadah said: He was called Yahya because Allah gave life to him with faith and Prophethood
>
> #### وقال مقاتل : اشتق اسمه من اسم الله تعالى حي فسمي يحيى .
>
> ... and Muqatil said He was named after the name of Allah: Haye.
>
> #### وقيل : لأنه أحيا به رحم أمه
>
> And it is also narrated that he was named so because through him Allah gave life to his mother's womb.

---

Secondly, there are other interpretations\translations of 19:7, which infer that Allah promised Zechariah a son like none that had been born before: abstaining from women, pure from sins, pious, given wisdom and knowledge of the scripture in his childhood, a mercy from Allah, dutiful to his parents, an attestor of Jesus etc.  <sup>[3:39](https://quran.com/3/39) , [19:12-13](https://quran.com/19/12-13)</sup>

See [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura19-aya7.html):

> #### . وقال مجاهد وغيره : سميا معناه مثلا ونظيرا ، وهو مثل قوله تعالى : هل تعلم له سميا معناه مثلا ونظيرا كأنه من المساماة والسمو ؛ وهذا فيه بعد ؛ لأنه لا يفضل على إبراهيم ؛ وموسى ؛ اللهم إلا أن يفضل في خاص كالسؤدد والحصر حسب ما تقدم بيانه ( في آل عمران ) .
>
> And Mujahid etc. said: سميا means example or likeness. The example of this is the saying of Allah [19:65](https://quran.com/19/65) هل تعلم له سميا   [ Do you know of any similarity to Him? ] the word is derived from المساماة والسمو there is a problem with this in that he didn't have absolute superiority over Abraham or Moses, but it can mean in specific attributes such as abstaining from women etc. as explained in Surah Ale Imaran.
>
> #### وقال ابن عباس أيضا : معناه لم تلد العواقر مثله ولدا . قيل : إن الله تعالى اشترط القبل ، لأنه أراد أن يخلق بعده أفضل منه وهو محمد - صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> Ibn Abbas said that it means that a barren woman has not given birth to a son like him. Some said that Allah put a condition of 'before him' since after him He sent Prophet Muhammad (p.b.u.h).

Comment: jazakallah. very helpful

Comment: The name Yahya is used exactly in the 1st book of Chronicles in verse 15:24. So, I think the first version is untenable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the muffasiron, there are different interpretations of the word "samiyya" in this context:

> يَا زَكَرِيَّا إِنَّا نُبَشِّرُكَ بِغُلَامٍ اسْمُهُ يَحْيَىٰ لَمْ نَجْعَل لَّهُ مِن قَبْلُ سَمِيًّا
>
> [Surat Maryam, verse 7](https://quran.com/19/7)

The apparent meaning which many translators include is that no one before him was named Yahya. This is supported and mentioned in the tafsirs as well. See Tabari, Razi. Which we find translated here:

> [He was told], "O Zechariah, indeed We give you good tidings of a boy whose name will be John. We have not assigned to any before [this] name."
>
> Sahih International

---

However they also mention views that what it really means is that no one ***like*** Yahya has been before him. This interpretation is found in Tafsir Tabari, Razi, Ibn Al-Kathir and so on. Shakir also translated it accordingly:

> O Zakariya! surely We give you good news of a boy whose name shall be Yahya: We have not made before anyone his equal.
>
> Shakir

One of the reasons for this interpretation is another verse (in the same chapter) mentions the word "samiyya", a rhetorical question, referring to if there is someone similar to God:

> رَّبُّ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ وَمَا بَيْنَهُمَا فَاعْبُدْهُ وَاصْطَبِرْ لِعِبَادَتِهِ ۚ **هَلْ تَعْلَمُ لَهُ سَمِيًّا**
>
> Lord of the heavens and the earth and whatever is between them - so worship Him and have patience for His worship. **Do you know of any similarity to Him?**"
>
> [Surat Maryam, verse 65](https://quran.com/19/65)

Razi in his [Tafsir](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/19/maryam/7/razi) also continues to mention some interpretations and discusses that Yahya was the first which God "personally" named. Because normally it is the people or parents who name their children:

> أن كل الناس إنما يسميهم آباؤهم وأمهاتهم بعد دخولهم في الوجود، وأما يحيى عليه السلام فإن الله تعالى هو الذي سماه قبل دخوله في الوجود فكان ذلك من خواصه فلم يكن له مثل وشبيه في هذه الخاصية.
>
> [Tafsir Razi](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/19/maryam/7/razi)

### Conclusion

So basically the scholars of Tafsir mention different of interpretations about the meaning of that verse, where that no one before was named Yahya seems to be one interpretation, but that seems not to be the most popular view among them.

Comment: very helpgul. jazakallah